Widgets associated with QListWidgeItem cannot be found by pywinauto backend=uia
The log results printed by pywinauto(app['Dialog'].print_control_identifiers()):

Control Identifiers:

Dialog - 'testUI'    (L629, T109, R1930, B1283)
['testUIDialog', 'Dialog', 'testUI']
child_window(title="testUI", auto_id="testUIClass", control_type="Window")
   | 
   | TitleBar - ''    (L645, T81, R1930, B109)
   | ['TitleBar']
   |    | 
   |    | Menu - '系统'    (L629, T86, R651, B108)
   |    | ['Menu', '系统Menu', '系统', '系统0', '系统1']
   |    | child_window(title="系统", auto_id="MenuBar", control_type="MenuBar")
   |    |    | 
   |    |    | MenuItem - '系统'    (L629, T86, R651, B108)
   |    |    | ['系统MenuItem', 'MenuItem', '系统2']
   |    |    | child_window(title="系统", control_type="MenuItem")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - '最小化'    (L1791, T79, R1838, B109)
   |    | ['Button', '最小化', '最小化Button', 'Button0', 'Button1']
   |    | child_window(title="最小化", control_type="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - '最大化'    (L1838, T79, R1884, B109)
   |    | ['Button2', '最大化', '最大化Button']
   |    | child_window(title="最大化", control_type="Button")
   |    | 
   |    | Button - '关闭'    (L1884, T79, R1931, B109)
   |    | ['Button3', '关闭', '关闭Button']
   |    | child_window(title="关闭", control_type="Button")
   | 
   | ListBox - ''    (L1429, T159, R2230, B1270)
   | ['ListBox']
   | child_window(auto_id="testUIClass.listWidget", control_type="List")
   |    | 
   |    | ListItem - ''    (L1431, T161, R2228, B261)
   |    | ['ListItem']
   | 
   | Button - 'PushButton'    (L699, T479, R842, B540)
   | ['Button4', 'PushButton', 'PushButtonButton', 'PushButton0', 'PushButton1', 'PushButtonButton0', 'PushButtonButton1']
   | child_window(title="PushButton", auto_id="testUIClass.pushButton", control_type="Button")
   | 
   | Button - 'PushButton'    (L699, T599, R870, B640)
   | ['Button5', 'PushButton2', 'PushButtonButton2']
   | child_window(title="PushButton", auto_id="testUIClass.pushButton_2", control_type="Button")


ListItem is associated with a QWidget object, which has some Qt default child controls.
Except for the child controls under the widget associated with the listItem, all other controls can be found.
The QT version is 5.14.2.
Here is my UI parent-child relationship:

"" testUI(0xf422fbfa90, name="testUIClass") Address: "0xf422fbfa90"
"    " CList(0x2096083b010, name="listWidget") Address: "0x2096083b010"
"        " QWidget(0x20960857a90, name="qt_scrollarea_viewport") Address: "0x20960857a90"
"            " TestWidget(0x20960870f80, name="TestWidget") Address: "0x20960870f80"
"                " QPushButton(0x209608d6240, name="pushButton") Address: "0x209608d6240"
"                " QLabel(0x209608d6f60, name="label") Address: "0x209608d6f60"
"                " QLabel(0x209608d66a0, name="label_2") Address: "0x209608d66a0"
"                " QLabel(0x209608d5de0, name="label_3") Address: "0x209608d5de0"
"        " QWidget(0x2096080d5f0, name="qt_scrollarea_hcontainer") Address: "0x2096080d5f0"
"            " QScrollBar(0x209608582e0) Address: "0x209608582e0"
"        " QWidget(0x2096080ce10, name="qt_scrollarea_vcontainer") Address: "0x2096080ce10"
"            " QScrollBar(0x20960858660) Address: "0x20960858660"
"    " QPushButton(0x20960860df0, name="pushButton") Address: "0x20960860df0"
"    " QPushButton(0x20960860d10, name="pushButton_2") Address: "0x20960860d10"


Can't find 3 QLabels and 1 QPushButton in TestWidget using pywinauto.
How can I see the information of all child controls under the widget associated with the QListWidgetItem in pywinauto?
Maybe the accessibility support of QListWidget unable to support the display of child controls of items?

Most probably it is lack of Microsoft UI Automation API support on Qt side. In theory it is possible to implement special Qt backend in pywinauto using DLL injection approach, but I don't have resources for it right now. So it is a very long term wish.

What "child controls"? Are you using setItemWidget() or are those the actual editors of the delegates? In the latter case, how/when are those editors opened? From the UI perspective, both item widgets and editors are just grandchildren of the list widget (they are children of its viewport), but it shouldn't matter that much, as long as those widgets are actually interactive (and standard, common controls).

Qt has own QML widgets hierarchy which may be different from MS UI Automation API hierarchy. That's why DLL injection to access internal Qt API is necessary for some widgets. pywinauto's backend "uia" doesn't use any Qt API directly, it uses Microsoft's UI Automation API available in OS by default. Qt may support or may not support some widgets on application side. Some special "server" C++ code is necessary for each widget to make it visible to clients like pywinauto.
